# How dictionaries are getting implemented here?

Tags: python, list

I am new to python. I came across this code while studying dictionaries. One thing which I don't get is how `counts`, which is only declared as a dictionary in the first line , is used in the if statement for searching names within it when no value has been added to it.

```html
counts = dict() 
names = ['csev' , 'cwen' , 'csev' , 'zqian' , 'cwen' ]
for name in names:
    if name not in counts: 
        counts[name] = 1
    else: 
        counts[name] = counts[name]+1
print(counts)     # typo
```

Comment: If the dict is empty then `name not in counts` will return `True` - what exactly is confusing about this to you?

Comment: Basically, it's to find the `name` to see if that is in the dict - `count`  (key searching). If not , then just build it by put it in the dict.

Comment: `collections.Counter` handles this use-case. `counts = Counter(names)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can try in this platform - https://pythontutor.com/
You could see what's happening in each step of execution.  But here is a simple  explanation.

```
counts = dict()     # 
names = ['csev' , 'cwen' , 'csev' , 'zqian' , 'cwen' ]

for name in names:            # looping each name in the list
    if name not in counts:    # check if it in the dict. counts (by key)
        counts[name] = 1      # if not, add it, and value set to 1 initially
    else: 
        counts[name] = counts[name]+1   # if existing, add value+1
print(count)
```

output

```
 {'csev': 2, 'cwen': 2, 'zqian': 1}
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it now, how it is working. Really appreciated.

Comment: Try that great visual platform - it should enable some easy debugging...

Comment: I will definitely use it. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is an "associative" list which means that to add content or access to it, instead of numerical indices (as for list/tuple), it can be done by for example strings or any *hashable* objects (`{1: 'a', []: 'b}` here is incorrect since a key is a list which is unhashable).

```
names = ['csev' , 'cwen' , 'csev' , 'zqian' , 'cwen' ]
counts = {}
for name in names:
    if name not in counts:
        counts[name] = 1
    else:
        counts[name] += 1 # <- increment

print(counts)
```

Since this kind of tasks are a kind of routine the standard library provides a special subclass of `dict` for it: (subclass means that has all the functionality of a dictionary plus some more stuffs, see the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter))

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(names)
print(c)
#Counter({'csev': 2, 'cwen': 2, 'zqian': 1})
```